# matplotlib.pyplot.scatter - define sizes of entries in legend for size of marker

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

How to change the marker size and the respective label in the legend to meaningful values like [20,40,60,80] ?
Do I need to derive handles and labels from an additional dummy dataset and how to plot it, so that it will not be visible (alpha=0.0 will not work?)?

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [1,2,3,4,5]
size = np.asarray([0.84,0.53,0.24,0.47,0.18]) * 100

s1 = plt.scatter(x, y, s=size)
handles, labels = s1.legend_elements(prop="sizes")
legend2 = plt.legend(handles, labels, frameon=False, title="Sizes")

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

The function [`legend_elements(...)`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PathCollection.legend_elements) has a parameter `num=` which can be a [`Locator`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.Locator).  So, you can try e.g. a [`MultipleLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
import numpy as np

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
size = np.asarray([0.84, 0.53, 0.24, 0.47, 0.18]) * 100

s1 = plt.scatter(x, y, s=size)
handles, labels = s1.legend_elements(prop="sizes", num=MultipleLocator(20))
legend2 = plt.legend(handles, labels, frameon=False, title="Sizes")

plt.show()
```

[image: using legend_elements with a locator]

PS: In this case, you can also just put a number for `num=`, e.g. `s1.legend_elements(prop="sizes", num=4)`. That also seems to put rounded values.  When only a few different size values are used in the plot, the default `num='auto'`, uses these values instead of rounded values.